# Fastapi alias for url/router/endpoint (set same handler for them)

Tags: fastapi

How I can make alias (call the same handler) for similar url/routers like `https://myapi/users/5` and `https://myapi/users/me` (my id placed in token and it's 5).

```py
    @router.get("/{employee_id}}", status_code=200, response_model=schemas.EmployeeOut)
    async def get_employee(
            employee_id: int = Path(default=..., ge=0, description='Id получаемого сотрудника.', example=8),
            token: str = Depends(config.oauth2_scheme),
            postgres_session: AsyncSession = Depends(database.get_db)):
        try:
            token_payload = services.get_token_payload(token=token)
            if token_payload['role'] in (config.OPERATOR_ROLE, config.OPERATOR_ROLE, config.CLINIC_ROLE):
                return (await postgres_session.execute(statement=models.employees.select().where(
                    models.employees.c.id == employee_id))).fetchone()
            else:
                raise config.known_errors['forbidden']
        except Exception as error:
            services.error_handler(error)
    
    # Just as example!
    @router.get("/me}", status_code=200, response_model=List[schemas.TicketOut])
    async def get_me(
            token: str = Depends(config.oauth2_scheme)):
        token_payload = services.get_token_payload(token=token)
        get_employee(employee_id=token_payload['sub'])
```

These functions is almost identical, the one difference is that in the second function no path parameter `employee_id`, but it's anyway are present in the token.

You can wonder why you need `me` url - it's just for convenience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. You can specify multiple decorators with API path specifications.
If you look closely at, say, `router.post` implementation, you will see, that the decorator returns not the wrapped function, but the original function, so you can safely pass it to another decorator.

Something like this:

```py
@router.post('/api/action1')
@router.post('/api/action2')
def do_action():
  pass
```

Comment: I want to write a function which takes an image id and  read the database table for imageID = img001 and will show all the metadata for that image.

like http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img001 

Then I wanted aliases like below...
    http://localhost:8000/myimage/001    -> http://localhost:8000/photo/?id=img001

There is a separate system to add the images into the database and that is dynamic and anytime a new image can come so I cannot configure and populate these aliases beforehand - they need to be dynamically aliased like above. 

Is it possible in fastapi ?

Comment: @NDS do you mean you nead to dynamically create routes? Like `/myimage/,,,`, `/photo/...`, `/great-photo/...` etc.? I think for this you need at least some part of route being static, like having prefix `/images/`. Then you can go with only 2 routes:


  @router.get('/images/{suffix}/{image_id}')
  def get_image(suffix: str, image_id: str):
    handle_image(suffix, image_id)

  @router.get('/images/{suffix}')
  def get_image_by_query(suffix: str, image_id: str = Query(...)):  
    handle_image(suffix, image_id)

Comment: Thanks @Minstel, Yes /myimage/... can be fixed - just want the rest as dynamic so anytime imagN is added into the database then    localhost:8000/myimage/N will auto-redirect  to  localhost:8000/photo/?id=imgN - without manually adding that particular route alias...

Answer (score 1):

The `/me` endpoint needs to be above the `/{employee_id}`
Check out this link: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters

Comment: Thank u for the refinement, but a question in another words, - is how to set multiple decorators for the same handler